# How to reduce query response time for the first query in MongoDB?

Tags: performance, mongodb, indexing

I have a collection in MongoDB with 20 million documents and an index created for the collection. I have confirmed that the find() query uses the index (col_1_col_2) (confirmed using the explain). However, I've noticed that the very first find() query in a day takes 5-10 sec, but all subsequent queries take less than 100 ms.

Updated DB stats:
db..stats()
ns  .
count   20135438
size    5694.57m
avgObjSize  296.55146314672
storageSize 7109.57m
numExtents  35
nindexes    4
lastExtentSize  1188.86m
paddingFactor   1
flags   1
totalIndexSize  3044.69m
indexSizes  {
   "*id*": 653319632,
   "col_1_col_2": 691730480,
   "col2_1": 848832320,
   "col1_1": 998706576 
}
ok  1
{top:1}
total   18
readLock    16

Questions:
1 Why does the first query take longer time? 
2 Is this to do with loading the index in RAM?

Comment: need to see both your document outline, and what your index's look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the disk activity during this first request. It could be related to mounting data from disk to RAM.

If you use linux : iostat -m 1  will help you.

Comment: *iostat not iostats.  Needs to be installed via apt-get install sysstat

Comment: Try that on a CentOS or RHEL machine. ;)